# How to reprogram key fob remote for central lock?

Tags: vw, central-locking

I have a 2000 vintage Volkswagen Golf mk.4. As it came from Wolfsburg it had central locking but no remote control on keys. Somewhere along the time I had **aftermarket** remote installed and received two key fobs.
A few weeks ago my battery died. I don't know if this was the cause or just coincidence. But I noticed that my key fob remotes do not work any more.
My first suspicion was that the codes for key fobs were erased so I thought to recode the remote to fobs. But here is the problem. The instructions are nonexistent. I have searched over the internet for some generic tips on how to do it, but every procedure I tried had no result. I also could not find manuals on net for my model. I also do not think it is bad battery in key fobs as both stopped working at the same time.
I have posted a picture of a box the remote came in. If someone can recognize the model or know how to reprogram this things I would like to know how it is done. Perhaps there is a reset/recode button on the remote vontrol box itself, yet I do not know exactly where in the car it was installed. So I tried stackexchange, before I start tearing the car apart.
The location where the control box is usually put in Golfs mk.4 would also be useful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: They seem to have quite a few products on their website.  You would need to supply a part number or something that could identify the product that you have.       http://www.spy-europe.nl/

Comment: @DucatiKiller I am aware f that. Yet this Control remote keyless entry is quite old and I doubt they have it in their current product line. I laso have no product number, it is not on the carboard box.

Comment: I don't see how the procedure could be researched without identifying the actual unit.  Can you find a part/serial number on the unit itself?

Comment: @DucatiKillerFor this I would have to find the actual unit itself. I do not know where it was built in. Hence my subquestion where is the usual place that this sucker is installed. If I do not get a pointer fr this I will star dismantling dashboard on driver's side under steering wheel (near fuse box). It just might be that the unit has a button or something to recode the fobs.